# syntax for nested random effects using gamm or lme in R

Tags: r, mixed-models, gam

I would like to fit three random effects to a gamm in R, including one that is nested in another.

For independent random effects, the `gamm` function in the `mgcv` package allows specification of the random effects using the list syntax from `lme`, i.e:

```
model<- gamm(y~s(x), random = list(ran1=~1,ran2=~1), data=data)
```

This works fine. However, I would like to have 'ran2' nested inside a third variable, 'ran3'. I can't seem to find any examples, for either `gamm` or `lme` that show how to nest random effects within the list syntax.

Neither of these work:

```
model<- gamm(y~s(x), random = list(ran1=~1,ran2/ran3=~1), data=data) #error unexpected '='
model<- gamm(y~s(x), random = list(~1|ran1,~1|ran2/ran3), data=data) #error must be a named list
```

This runs:

```
model<- gamm(y~s(x), random = list(ran1=~1,ran3=~ran2), data=data)
```

but produces warnings about fewer observations than random effects (which shouldn't be the case with my data), so I think that syntax isn't doing what I want.

I suppose a simple option might be to create a version of ran3 that is obligatorily nested in ran2, i.e. each level of ran3 only occurs within a single level of ran2. Would that make `gamm` recognise the nesting structure?

Comment: Ah - I have discovered the `gamm4` package allows you to specify random variables as per lmer formula syntax, which is easier. So this does not answer the question for `mgcv` but might help anyone who does not mind shifting to `gamm4`.